# Округление чисел в нескольких тегах с одинаковым классом Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем,

```
<div class="price-round">111.26</div>
<div class="price-round">222.49</div>
<div class="price-round">333.56</div>
<div class="price-round">444.96</div>
```

Необходимо округлить значения в большую сторону и вставить их на свои же места, количество цен на странице может меняться.

В результате нужно получить:

```
<div class="price-round">112</div>
<div class="price-round">223</div>
<div class="price-round">334</div>
<div class="price-round">445</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.price-round').each(function(){
  $(this).text(Math.ceil($(this).text()));
});
```

Comment: В округление в _большую_ сторону — `Math.ceil()`

Comment: не обратил внимания что интересует именно в большую. спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".price-round").each(function(){
    $(this).text(Math.ceil(parseFloat($(this).text())));
});
```